# How to manage internal and external mode for a mobile app in the same code base

Tags: html, mobile

I'm developing a mobile app, and I want to maintain:

- an external version for users
- an internal version for development purposes

The differences between the versions are minor.
For example, the internal version will have another button that directs to a local machine on the LAN.

I can manage the differences by having 2 separate git branches and switching between them.
But it feels to me like a big overhead to keep syncing between the 2 branches, whenever code changes are made.
Instead, I'm looking for some configuration file that can control the mode.

Is there a best practice on how to handle this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a git branch my-project-internal from the main branch my-project.
I switch between the 2 branches when I need a specific configuration.
Once in a while I sync the development branch my-project-internal with the main branch my-project, using

```
git checkout my-project
git pull
git checkout my-project-internal
git rebase my-project
```